# PHP display project directory

Tags: php

I have a current url like this `http://localhost/prototype/images/noalbums.php`.

I've been trying some sort of `$_SERVER $_FILE` to get my project directory which is `prototype` directory.

Then how can I extract `prototype` from the URL `http://localhost/prototype/images/noalbums.php` which is my main directory?

Comment: is this just a normal php or is this a php frame work ?

Comment: standard php without framework

Answer (score 2):

You could grab `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, which I believe should return everything after example. So you'd have a string `prototype/images/noalbums.php`

Parsing it from there should be easy,

```
    $uri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $urlComponents = explode('/',$uri);
```

This would create an array stored in `$urlComponents` like so.

```
    $urlComponents[0] => 'prototype'
    $urlComponents[1] => 'images'
    $urlComponents[2] => 'noalbums.php'
```

Since it's an array, you could then iterate through that array to pull out the elements you'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

create a file inside prototype called `dirconfig.php` in that file place the following statements.

```
define('BASE', basename(__DIR__));
```

then you can access the constant `BASE` from any file which you include this file in. it will have the value of your base directory.

Comment: wouldn't the document root return the path up to `/images` ?

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT  returns path up to `/` of localhost. its same as DocumentRoot configured in the web server.

Comment: i tried that and it displays C:/xampp/htdocs/prototype. All I just wanted is get the main directory name